# Recursive code is hard to understand - need to simplify

Tags: c#, recursion

I have an entity and I can have InvoiceLine on top of that, then you can credit that invoice line infinite no of times. but only main InvoiceLine have reference to original entity.

I am using recursion to get the original entity , but the code is not that readable

```
private static PermanentPlacement PopulatePermanentPlacement(InvoiceLine invoiceLine)
        {
            PermanentPlacement permanentPlacement;
            var creditReissue = invoiceLine.CreditReissue;
            do
            {
                permanentPlacement = creditReissue.InvoiceLine.PermanentPlacement;
                if (permanentPlacement == null)
                {
                    creditReissue = creditReissue.InvoiceLine.CreditReissue;
                }
            } while(permanentPlacement == null);

            return permanentPlacement;
        }
```

Is there any way I can make this more readable and simplify ?

Comment: You are not in fact using recursion here.

Comment: but your code is not recursive

Comment: This is not recursion.

Comment: It sounds like you want code review. One thing I see is that the variable names are all really long. Try to shorten them. Oh, and the code is not recursive. Recursive code calls the same function over and over until it reaches its end.

Comment: There's nothing unreadable about this code...it's pretty basic.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Shortening the names would make it *less* readable.  There certainly isn't superfluous information in the variable names here.

Comment: Do not shorten the variable names. Long variable names make code easier to understand.

Comment: @EvanCarslake -- I agree with the other two, and those variable names are *not* long at all.  Why would you elect to shorten them?  Think about your reasoning, I think you may find you don't actually have a concrete reason.  Long variable names supplement code comments in helping future devs know what's going on.

Comment: I notice that in your code you never return the `PermanentPlacement` of the *original* `invoiceLine`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @EricLippert -yes because I will come to this function only when original invoiceline have placement null

Comment: Well in that case you can make the code even shorter still. `while(invoiceLine.PermanentPlacement == null) invoiceLine = invoiceLine.CreditReissue.InvoiceLine; return invoiceLine.PermanentPlacement;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer by René Vogt shows the best way to simplify this code. But there are others. For example, consider moving the loop to a helper function:

```
static IEnumerable<Reissue> CreditReissues(Reissue original)
{
  var current = original;
  while(true) 
  {
    yield return current;
    current = current.InvoiceLine.CreditReissue;
  } 
}
```

And now you don't ever need to write a loop again in order to use an infinite sequence of credit reissues:

```
private static PermanentPlacement PopulatePermanentPlacement(
  InvoiceLine invoiceLine)
{
  return CreditReissues(invoiceLine.CreditReissue)
    .Select(cr => cr.InvoiceLine.PermanentPlacement)
    .First(pp => pp != null);
}
```

That is: take the infinite sequence of credit reissues, turn it into an infinite sequence of permanent placements, and return the first non-null one in the sequence.

Notice how by changing the loop into a sequence, we can now describe the operations we want to perform *on the level of sequences* and not *on the level of statements and variables*.

Incidentally, you say -- twice -- that you are using recursion in the original code, but you are not.  A recursive solution would look like this:

```
private static PermanentPlacement PopulatePermanentPlacement(
  InvoiceLine invoiceLine)
{
  return invoiceLine.PermanentPlacement ??
         PopulatePermanentPlacement(
           invoiceLine.CreditReissue.InvoiceLine);
}
```

You should not use a recursive solution for a potentially unbounded loop because C# is not guaranteed to be *tail recursive*, and therefore can blow the stack.

Answer (score 2):

I would shorten the code to:

```
private static PermanentPlacement PopulatePermanentPlacement(InvoiceLine invoiceLine)
{
    var creditReissue = invoiceLine.CreditReissue;
    while(creditReissue.InvoiceLine.PermanentPlacement == null)
        creditReissue = creditReissue.InvoiceLine.CreditReissue;

    return creditReissue.InvoiceLine.PermanentPlacement;
}
```

This does the same as your code, except that it accesses `PermantPlacement` of the final `InvoiceLine` an extra time. So if this property getter does more than just returning a value, this modification may not be valid.

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems pretty clear and readable to me. René Vogt's answer is about as short as you could make it without changing the logic but I have a gut feeling that what you really want might be this:

```
private static PermanentPlacement PopulatePermanentPlacement(InvoiceLine invoiceLine)
{
    var creditReissue = invoiceLine.CreditReissue;
    while (creditReissue.InvoiceLine.CreditReissue != null)
    {
        // Get the last credit reissue
        creditReissue = creditReissue.InvoiceLine.CreditReissue;
    }
    return creditReissue.InvoiceLine.PermanentPlacement;    
}
```

It does change the logic a bit, please validate that it is equivalent.